# Is it possible to embedd the UI of DApp in the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, dapps, gui

I have read the answers for [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122/how-to-create-a-dapp-from-scratch-on-ethereum) as well as their linked resources, but I didn't found the answer for the following question:

- is it possible to embedd the UI of ÐApp in the blockchain?

If I provide the UI (HTML, js) for the distributed app, then I retain some kind of possibility to change the way my application is working, according to my current needs. I can hide or process some information, I can store the user input in my database etc. But I would like to ensure the end users of my app that I'm not able to intercept or change theirs data.

Comment: I am assuming that you are building a web app, if you deploy the code on blockchain how your users access the front end? Blockchain will not render html. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @NikhilM "if you deploy the code on blockchain how your users access the front end?" - exactly, that is the question. I mean, can I define the UI of the application in the blockchain in a way that will be accessible to end user? Embedded HTML files or something like that?

Comment: Yes, you can embed data in the blockchain, any kind of data. But the Dapp you build must parse the content from the blockchain and show what it is to the user. I guess that is not what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could deploy the app through [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) and publish the hashes of the file on the blockchain. In this way you don't have to control its distribution and users can be assured they are getting the correct files.

The [embark framework](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework) can automatically deploy to IPFS.

Comment: Yeah, also there is IPFS plugin to create a hash for a folder irrespective of the inner contents. that may be useful for the OP