# Possible maximum size of a website built from smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development

This article titled "Real World Use Cases for Ethereum" ([here at blokt.com](https://blokt.com/guides/ethereum-guides/eth-use-cases)) mentions one interesting use case for smart contracts: web hosting.

The article says that

> Using Ethereum, web hosting could become a decentralized,
>   network-based business.  In other words, a website would be hosted by
>   the entire Ethereum network, making it virtually impossible to take
>   down or tamper with.

This sounds like an interesting possible real-life use case for smart contracts, but many websites have requirements for available network bandwidth or the ability to host downloadable files (e.g. PDFs).

Assuming though that at least a small(ish) website is technically feasible, is there any information on what might be the maximum size of a website built from smart contracts?

Comment: See [Is it possible to embedd the UI of DApp in the blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1881/is-it-possible-to-embedd-the-ui-of-dapp-in-the-blockchain).

Comment: Note that Web3 is more than just the Ethereum blockchain; it's also Swarm (decentralized content storage/distribution network, basically what you want) and Whisper (decentralized p2p messaging).