# Where was the example web app to send Gavin Ether?

Tags: ether

I once found an example webapp where you could send Gavin ether through a webform.
Anyone know where it was?

Comment: Any particular Gavin, or did it just pick one at random?

Comment: gavin wood, i think he's one of the main developers

Comment: Are you really just looking for an address associated with him, or for a tutorial on how to make a Dapp?

Comment: I think it was ment as part of a tutorial example.

Comment: In that case, this thread might be of use: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122/how-to-create-a-dapp-from-scratch-on-ethereum/1250#1250